# SVG center text in circle

Tags: html, css, svg, geometry, center

I am trying to center text in a SVG circle.
Looked att previous solutions, however can't make it work.

How can I get the following example center the 'X' i the circle not modifying the x/y coordinates or font size?

The red cross indicating the middle.

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px">
  <circle r="50" cx="100" cy="100"></circle>  
  <text x="100" y="100" fill="white" 
       font-size="100" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" 
       font-family="Verdana">X</text>  
  <line x1="50" y1="100" x2="150" y2="100" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"></line>
  <line x1="100" y1="50" x2="100" y2="150" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"></line>     
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the **dy** attribute of the `<text`> element to move the text slightly upward. Then **dy** attribute controls the vertical offset of the text relative to the y-coordinate. look at the example:

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px">
    <circle r="50" cx="100" cy="100"></circle>  
    <text x="100" y="100" fill="white" font-size="100" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" font-family="Verdana" dy=".10em">X</text>  
    <line x1="50" y1="100" x2="150" y2="100" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"></line>
    <line x1="100" y1="50" x2="100" y2="150" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"></line>     
</svg>
```

Comment: `<text x="50%" y="50%"` might be more flexible?

Comment: You will not get good results without "dy"

Answer (score 0):

You forget to use a viewbox (and that's really bad :/)

You may simply adjust your text `y` position... ?

```css
svg {
  width      : 200px;
  height     : 200px;
  background : yellow;
  }
svg circle {
  fill       : black;
  }
svg text {
  font-family : verdana;
  fill        : lightskyblue; 
  text-anchor : middle;
  }
svg line {
  stroke       : red;
  stroke-width : 2;
  }
```

```html
<svg viewbox="50 50 100 100" >
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50"            ></circle>  
  <text    x="100"  y="136" font-size="100"   >X</text>  
  <line   x1="50"  y1="100" x2="150" y2="100" ></line>
  <line   x1="100" y1="50"  x2="100" y2="150" ></line>     
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the [dominant-baseline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline) attribute that controls how the text is placed, but in the end it depends on the font that you are using. Sometimes the value `central` is better when you have a capital letter.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <circle r="50" cx="100" cy="100"/>  
  <text x="100" y="100" fill="white" font-size="100" text-anchor="middle"
    dominant-baseline="central" font-family="Verdana">X</text>  
  <line x1="50" y1="100" x2="150" y2="100" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"/>
  <line x1="100" y1="50" x2="100" y2="150" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"/>     
</svg>
```